# c++ operator int is called in the code why?

Tags: c++

In the below code snippet

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int i) : m_i(i) { }

public:
    int operator()(int i = 0) const 
    {
        return m_i + i; 
    }

    operator int () const
    {
        return m_i;
    }
    operator float () const
    {
        return 0.0;
    }

private:
    int m_i;

    friend int g(const A&);
};

int f(char c)
{
    return c;
}

int g(const A& a)
{
    return a.m_i;
}

int main()
{
    A f(2), g(3);
    int i = f;// call 1

    std::cout << f(1) << g(f) << std::endl;// call 2

    return 0;
}
```

I gave some comments like call 1 and call 2  in the main function.
I understood why operator int is called  at *call 1*.
But I could not understand why at // call 2
Can some body explain me why it is so.

Comment: Get rid of your `f` and `g` functions. They aren't being used in the code.

Comment: Perhaps it will become clearer if you don't name a variable and a function by the same name.

Comment: Its question in online test. I just copied here.

Comment: Simply dont judge that I did this. After reading the answers only, I come to know that, the question is to confuse the f and g. Just because you have knife, dont cut others throat. Please dont minus my points. Its a valid question from an online test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::cout << f(1) << g(f) << std::endl;
```

Let's break this down into function calls instead of operators. (This might not be technically correct syntax.)

```
int temp1 = f.operator()(1);
ostream& temp2 = std::cout.operator<<(temp1);
// By the implementation of ostream::operator<<, temp2 is a reference to std::cout.
// The compiler doesn't know this, though, and must treat it as if it could be different.
int temp3 = f.operator int(); // Typecast since A::operator() expects an `int`.
int temp4 = g.operator()(temp3);
ostream& temp5 = temp2.operator<<(temp4);
// temp5 is another reference to std::cout.
temp5.operator<<(std::endl);
// Result discarded.
```

Answer (score 2):

The function g is hidden by the g (of type A) in scope. So g(f) converts f to int then calls g.operator()(int) with the result of the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

When you call g(f), A::operator()(int i=0) is called for g.

f must therefore be converted into an int, which is done via A::operator int() .